# Ubuntu 13.04 - Driver/Header/Icon problems resulting in weird Theme loss?

Tags: unity, gnome, nvidia, compiz, themes

So, after trying to setup Bumblebee, I did mess up a lot of my Ubuntu installations, including installing and taking down Nvidia drivers - resolving mirrored and flipped text issues, and well - I managed to do all that, except that now icons and most of GUI elements are just black and white.

I would guess it's related to Linux-headers - as the problem appeared somewhere in that timespan.

Also it could be with 3d acceleration related things? I'm not sure, my first week on Linux.

So - now it looks like this.

[image]

I've tried reinstalling both compiz / unity following instructions around. Tried fallback to Gnome (no idea), didn't help either. Any solutions?

Loading CCSM from Terminal gives this:

```
Gtk-WARNING : Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "hcengine",
```

-- lshw -c video information

```
   *-display               
   description: VGA compatible controller
   product: GF108M [GeForce GT 540M]
   vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
   version: a1
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
   configuration: driver=nvidia latency=0
```

--

```
   *-display
   description: VGA compatible controller
   product: Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 2
   bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
   version: 02
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
   configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
   resources: irq:43 memory:d1400000-d17fffff memory:c0000000-cfffffff ioport:4050(size=8)
```

-- unity_support_test

```
OpenGL vendor string:   Intel Open Source Technology Center
OpenGL renderer string: Mesa DRI Intel(R) Ironlake Mobile 
OpenGL version string:  2.1 Mesa 9.1.3

Not software rendered:    yes
Not blacklisted:          yes
GLX fbconfig:             yes
GLX texture from pixmap:  yes
GL npot or rect textures: yes
GL vertex program:        yes
GL fragment program:      yes
GL vertex buffer object:  yes
GL framebuffer object:    yes
GL version is 1.4+:       yes

Unity 3D supported:       yes
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, remove all your Nvidia drivers and bumblebee:

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia*
sudo apt-get purge bumblebee*
```

Then install the current Nvidia drivers:

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-current
```

Comment: did both already

would rather not install the nvidia-current, since it did break unity/compiz in first place

all I have now from nvidia is the nvidia-updates

Comment: I posted this as an answer because the source of the problem is probably caused by conflicting drivers. I've had a similar problem and this was the solution for me.